# Ruby script on ec2 boot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unix, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I would like to run a simple script on AWS EC2 , every time I spin up a new instance using AMI-xxxx

My script is already paced in AMI , but it should run on ec2 instance everytime I spin up a new instance

from terminal I can run script with

`ruby ~/script/couchbase-config.rb`

Is it also possible that it dont run every time I restart instance but only run only the very first time ec2 instance spin up ?

Answer (score 0):

in your script put a "lock"file somewhere (e.g. `/etc/couchbase-config-done`) and in the beginning of your script only continue the script if this file is not found.

however i do not understand who calls your script and why you cannot simply call it less often/only during/after instance creation not on every boot...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're configuring Couchbase environment variables.  Why not run the script, then create a new AMI from the one you've just run it on, with everything already configured?  If you're booting from an EBS snapshot, every subsequent instance you spin up will be configured the same way, but EC2 creates a new, unique EBS volume from the snapshot - that you can even persist if you need it after the instance is terminated.  I do this with spot instances.

Comment: no i am not trying to set environment variables for couchbase. I am doing this on every instance 
http://www.couchbase.com/docs/couchbase-manual-2.0/couchbase-getting-started-hostnames-pre2.0.html
its for public ip hostname setup

Comment: Perhaps post us the contents of your script to see your strategy?

Consider using a dynamic DNS provider and a cron job that updates the IP to the hostname, since it will be given a new Amazon IP each time you spin up a new VM in EC2. Many DDNS have a REST API, i.e. cURL or wget.

Is the idea to spin up a varying amount of instances to load-balance? Better to just do the math and find out how big of a cluster you actually need for your use-case, and set hostnames in the image. Key rebalancing and replication are time and resource-intensive if you are constantly bringing the nodes up and down.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to assign an IP to the node via script, register a domain name and add nodes to the cluster using their FQDN.  For example, you could give each machine it's own subdomain name under the unbrella of the primary domain in the zone record: (cb1.mydomain.com, cb2.mydomain.com, etc.)

Let your dynamic DNS provider handle the IP mappings.  If you're already on AWS EC2, you should try out their Route53 service.  When your EC2 image spins up, you update the A record for that subdomain based on the IP the VM is given at boot-time.  That IP may also change due to scheduled maintenance on EC2, so you could put it in a cron job if you like.

Check out the `fog` gem for handling DNS from Ruby:
http://fog.io/dns/

You could also use the AWS Route53 service from `route53`, a more lightweight gem since it only handles AWS DNS:
https://rubygems.org/gems/route53